# C# - Cant add hours to the current time

Tags: c#

I want to add time to the current time or in other words,i have time in UTC + 0, i want that time in UTC + 5.00, 
I can subtract as many hours as i can

- it works fine for "(20:15 current_time) - (10)"
- it works fine for "(20:12 current_time) - (10*324234 hours)"
- it works even when "(20:13 current_time) + (1)" addition
- but it doesnt work when "(20:13 current_time) + (5 hours)"

Code:

```
using System;

namespace week3
{

class LocalTime
{
    static string Time, City;
    static decimal time;

    public LocalTime(string city, double add) {
        Time = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(add));
        Time = Time.Substring(11, 5);
        time = Convert.ToDecimal(Time.Substring(0, 2) + "." + Time.Substring(3, 2));
        City = time.ToString();
        Time = City.Substring(0, 2) + ":" + City.Substring(3, 2);
        City = city;
        DisplayTimeAndCity("", "");

    }
    static void DisplayTimeAndCity(string x, string y)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(City + " - " +Time);
    }
}

class London : LocalTime {
    public London() : base("London", 0) {   
    }
}
class NewYork : LocalTime
{
    public NewYork(): base("NewYork", 5)
    {
    }
}
class Tokyo : LocalTime
{
    public Tokyo(): base("Tokyo", -9)
    {
    }
}
class HongKong : LocalTime
{
    public HongKong(): base("Hong Kong", -8)
    {
    }
}
class Test {
    static void Main() {
        London a = new London();
        NewYork b = new NewYork();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using string manipulations?

Comment: datetimevariable.AddHours(5); if u need to subtract AddHours(-5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "how to format `DateTime` value as `hours:minutes`":

```
 var time = (DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(3)).ToString("hh:mm");
```

More information on formatting options - [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Note that other answers suggest much better ways to deal with timezones via `TimeZoneInfo` or `DateTimeOffset`.

Answer (score 1):

To Add 5 hours to the a `DateTime` you could simply use the following:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
```

And there is also an easy function to substract from a DateTime:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

Comment: +0: OP already use reasonable `+ TimeSpan.FromHours(add)` already. `.AddHours(5)` is shorter, but unlikely to help much with very strange string slicing code (which potentially tries to do some something like `.ToString("hh:mm")` )...

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to represent the time in different time zones you might find [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382058.aspx) to be useful. Rather than defining several classes you might prefer to use something from the framework. The documentation for the strings which identify each zone is in the [TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) and the strings relate to the [TimeZone.Id property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx). I tested this on Windows 8.1, it worked fine.

> The time zone identifier is a key string that uniquely identifies a
>   particular time zone. In Windows XP and Windows Vista, it corresponds
>   to the subkeys of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zone branch of the registry. It can be passed
>   as a parameter to the FindSystemTimeZoneById method to retrieve a
>   particular time zone from the registry.

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Current Times:");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Los Angeles: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Pacific Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("Chicago: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Central Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("New York: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Eastern Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("London: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "GMT Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("Moscow: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Russian Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("New Delhi: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("Beijing: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "China Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine("Tokyo: {0}", 
                      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Tokyo Standard Time"));
}
```

This lists the time zones that can be found on the local machine:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
Console.WriteLine("The local system has the following {0} time zones", zones.Count);
foreach (TimeZoneInfo zone in zones)
   Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `DateTimeOffset` for your purpose:

```
DateTimeOffset dateTimeWithOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
```

With that, you will keep both the time, and the offset information in a standard way.